# is it possible to change the Audio output channel (3.5 mm Jack /usb soundcard or via gpio's) with MATLAB?

Tags: audio, matlab

i want to be able to change the audio output channel via Matlab.
is it Possible to apply these changes? (Signal Rooting)#
if there is a way, i would appreciate any help or guide.

thanks a lot

Comment: anything is possible